# How to upload an image on dropbox using its API V2 (in python)?

Tags: python, image, dropbox-api

I need to create a pipeline that would take an image from the dropbox, process it and upload it back (could be a different folder). The first two steps are easy, but there doesn't seem to be a way to upload the image to dropbox with the newer API V2. I have tried uploading a local image - read from computer and save it to dropbox, no success. The problem seems to be the format of the file, I get the following error:

```
expected request_binary as binary type
```

There are many examples for the text files and it works pretty well, while for the images the same solutions fail

```
import dropbox
from PIL import Image

dbx = dropbox.Dropbox('access_token') # Connecting to the account
metadata,file=dbx.files_download('/PATH_TO_IMAGE') # Getting the image from DropBox
im=Image.open(io.BytesIO(file.content)) # Getting the image to process

dbx.files_upload(im, '/PATH', mode=WriteMode('overwrite'))
```

Also tried:

```
dbx.files_upload_session_start(im)
```

Python3, dropbox SDK 9.4.0
actually I have tried putting the file in various formats, so instead of im there was also im.read(), np.array(im.getdata()).encode(), io.BytesIO(), local image from my computer but nothing works. And I do not understand how to transform the image data to 'request_binary as binary type'.

So what is needed, as I understand is a way to transform any file to 'request_binary'

```
TypeError: expected request_binary as binary type, got <class --SMTH ELSE-->
```

Comment: The `files_upload` method expects the file data as bytes. There's an example here: https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python/blob/master/example/updown.py#L177

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Greg I have found a solution, a bit easier than the one written in the example

```py
import dropbox
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import io


def load_image(filepath: str) -> bytes:
    image = Image.open(filepath)  # any image
    l = np.array(image.getdata())

    # To transform an array into image using PIL:
    channels = l.size // (image.height * image.width)
    l = l.reshape(image.height, image.width, channels).astype(
        "uint8"
    )  # unit8 is necessary to convert
    im = Image.fromarray(l).convert("RGB")

    # to transform the image into bytes:
    with io.BytesIO() as output:
        im.save(output, format="PNG")
        contents = output.getvalue()
    return contents

contents = load_image("1.png")
dbx = dropbox.Dropbox("access_token")  # Connecting to the account
dbx.files_upload(
    contents, "/FOLDER/IMAGE.png", dropbox.files.WriteMode.add, mute=True
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do this:

```py
import dropbox


def load_image(filepath: str) -> bytes:
    with open(filepath, "rb") as fp:
        contents = fp.read()
    return contents

contents = load_image("1.png")
dbx = dropbox.Dropbox("access_token")  # Connecting to the account
dbx.files_upload(
    contents, "/FOLDER/IMAGE.png", dropbox.files.WriteMode.add, mute=True
)
```